# How to pass parameters from view to an action in controller

Tags: zend-framework

result[$i]['id'].""; ?>">"Edit this Promotion"

Here "editpromotion" is the action to which I wish to pass the parameter:"$this->result[$i]['id']".

And in the controller action('editpromotionAction') :

I am using :

```
$pass = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->view->pass = $pass;
```

But the Output I am getting:

"array
  'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
  'action' => string 'editpromotion' (length=13)
  'module' => string 'default' (length=7)"

And can't see the parameter passed.

Please tell me where I am wrong and please specify me a solution for this Problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure the router, or use different link style (add `id` param):

```
<a href="<?php echo "editpromotion/id/".$this->result[$i]['id'].""; ?>">"Edit this</a>
```

or even better:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('module'=>'default', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'editpromotion', 'id'=>$this->result[$i]['id']), null, true); ?>">Edit this</a>
```